# How to create XML webparts using sharepoint web services?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, wss-3.0

I have an XML to be rendered in sharepoint using a XSL file. I now the how to do this using object model of sharepoint but don't how to do this using sharepoint web services.

i.e. I want to create XML web parts using sharepoint web services.

Is it possible to do create XML web parts using sharepoint web services? If yes, how?

Comment: I think you should be more precise and tell us what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself how to do it. :-)

The `AddWebPart` method of `WebPartPages`web service is the only method which can be used to add a web part and add it to a page too.

You only need to prepare the Xml properly which needs to be passed to the methosd as a parameter. This XML determines the type of WebPart and it's properties.

For Xml WebPArt, I used the following Xml:

```
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
          <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
          <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XmlWebPart</TypeName>
          <FrameType>None</FrameType>
          <Title>XML Web Part</Title>
          <XMLLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Xml">http://RootSite/sites/XYZ/Documents/ABC.xml</XMLLink>
          <XML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Xml" />
          <XSLLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Xml">http://RootSite/sites/XYZ/Documents/ABC.xsl</XSLLink>
          <XSL xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Xml" />
          <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Xml" />
</WebPart>
```

And pass this Xml string to the `AddWebPart` Method:

```
public static Guid WebPartPagesAddWebPart(string PageUrl, string WebPartXml, uint Storage)
        {
            // proxy object to call the Versions web service
            WebPartPages.WebPartPagesWebService WebPartPagesWebService = new WebPartPages.WebPartPagesWebService();

            // the user credentials to use
            WebPartPagesWebService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain);
            WebPartPagesWebService.Url = sharePointHost + WebPartPagesServiceName;

            // add the new web part to the page
            Guid Result = WebPartPagesWebService.AddWebPart(PageUrl, WebPartXml, (WebPartPages.Storage)Storage);

            // dispose the web service object
            WebPartPagesWebService.Dispose();
            return Result;
        }
```

The MSDN help only gave a example for ContentEditor web part. I searched a bit and modified it for Xml web part. :)